# Variable undefined when referenced in freemarker string but exists otherwise

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts2, freemarker

I'm quite new to Freemarker/Struts2/Spring/Hibernate etc., but I'm working on an old project. I've modified one of the FTL files to reflect some changes, and I've got an odd problem.

This works, i.e. the correct value is retrieved:

```
<@s.property value="#dataResult.gene.genbankId" />
```

However, this does not:

```
<a href="${geneBankLink}${dataResult.gene.genbankId}" target="_blank">
```

The two lines occur immediately one after the other, i.e.

```
<a href="${geneBankLink}${dataResult.gene.genbankId}" target="_blank">
<@s.property value="#dataResult.gene.genbankId" /> </a>
```

The error produced (in brief) is:

Expression dataResult.gene is undefined

freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression dataResult.gene is undefined on line 54, column 51 in web/search/search_data_result.ftl.

The odd thing to me is that it does find something as dataResult, otherwise the error would be dataResult is undefined, not dataResult.gene.

Is there a reason why the dataResult.gene attribute would be accessible through the struts notation, but not through the FreeMarker notation?

Alternatively, a way to avoid using the FreeMarker notation in this instance would suffice.

Comment: #dataResult is different than dataResult

Comment: Yes, but it is a syntax error to put # there... :s

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out after a couple of hours of trial and error that you can use the struts syntax even inside another tag!

So this actually works:

```
<a href="${geneBankLink}<@s.property value="#dataResult.gene.genbankId" />" target="_blank">
<@s.property value="#dataResult.gene.genbankId" /> </a>
```

Go figure. I'm still interested in finding out why it works / why it broke in the first place, but this is enough for me to be getting on with...

Comment: Why couldn't you? Nesting inside a *JSP* tag isn't legal, but HTML tags aren't processed by JSP (or FreeMarker), they're just part of the template.

Comment: Cool. I guess it just looked funny to me :) as you say, it's not a normal XML file though.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
<a href="${geneBankLink + #dataResult.gene.genbankId}" target="_blank">
```

`${}` - means expression and everything inside is treated more or less as a Java code (OGNL takes care of that), also `#` define a bit different behaviour how to resolve the value - search throughout the ActionContext to find value

http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/access-to-valuestack-from-jsps.html
http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/ognl.html

Comment: Oddly enough, any use of the hash inside the braces appears to result in a parsing error.

Comment: hmmm... did you try to remove the hash?